# How to clone without including input values (using

Tags: jquery, clone, auto-increment, watermark

I am trying to clone part of a form without including the information that the user inputs into the first form. I am using the In-Field Labels jQuery Plugin.

When I use val('') to address this problem, the value of the input is not duplicated, but the watermark for the In-Field Labels plugin doesn't appear as it should - it's just blank.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem, or even how to make the code I have more efficient/correct? Thank you.

```
(function() {
var count = 0;

  $('#add-standard-button').live('click',function () {

    var source = $('.details'),
        clone = source.clone();

    clone.find('.copyme').val('').attr('id', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
    });
    clone.find('.copyme').val('').attr('name', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
    });
    clone.find('.placeholder').val('').attr('for', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
    });

    clone.insertAfter('.details:last');

    count++;

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="details" id="standard-details">
  <div class="markName">
    <p>
     <span class="markName-field">
      <label for="markName" class="placeholder">
       <span>Watermark Text Goes Here</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="markName" id="markName" class="copyme">
     </span>
   </p> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the title tag on your inputs and then pull your default value from that.

```
clone.find('.copyme').val( $(this).attr('title').attr('name', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
```

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4KLU5/

Or you could use HTML5 data tags

```
      <input type="text" data-default="default text" name="markName" id="markName" class="copyme">
```

and

```
  clone.find('.copyme').val( $(this).data('default') ).attr('name', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to solve the problem. The watermark doesn't show up in the cloned field if the user has already entered text in the original.

Comment: They key to this is never destroying the watermark, if you use something like title or data-title, you will always be able to refer back to it as its part of the element.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/4KLU5/

Comment: I think I may be having problems here because the In-Field Labels jQuery Plugin uses the text between label tags as the watermark. I'm using the plugin instead of HTML5 because the the plugin shows a lighter version of the watermark when a user clicks inside the field. As far as know, HTML5 doesn't have that feature.

Comment: What I mean is that I want the watermark to appear even when the user clicks within the field, like Apple does with its search field (http://store.apple.com/us), or like Twitter does on its signup page (www.twitter.com). Is that possible with HTML5?

Comment: oh yeah, just fade it out a bit on click and then fade it totally out when there is a 'keydown' event'

Comment: Didn't realize that. Thank you! However, don't I still need a javascript backup for those not using browsers with HTML5?

Comment: Oh no, the data-whatever attribute works all the way back to IE5.5. Its not valid XHTML4 but its valid html5 that just happens to work in IE 5.5+